change the lower_case_table_names variable value 1 and restart my mysql not start and throw error
in my Ubuntu server into mysql

i have add the my.cnf file into this

lower_case_table_names=1

after restart my mysql using command

sudo systemctl restart mysql

Got an Error

"systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service"
what should do to run my mysql with my requirement ?
please anyone help me ... i am stuck

What MySQL version ? What is the output of systemctl status mysql.service and journalctl -xeu mysql.service ? lower_case_table_names It is prohibited to start the server with a lower_case_table_names setting that is different from the setting used when the server was initialized . MySQL Service not restarting after changing lower case table names.

mysql 8.0.XX  version and
error is Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.

hey this is solution :
for better Explanation click here
It is therefore necessary to configure lower_case_table_names to the desired setting before initializing the server. In most cases, this requires configuring lower_case_table_names in a MySQL option file before starting the MySQL server for the first time. For APT installations on Debian and Ubuntu, however, the server is initialized for you, and there is no opportunity to configure the setting in an option file beforehand.
You must therefore use the debconf-set-selection utility prior to installing MySQL using APT to enable lower_case_table_names.
To do so, run this command before installing MySQL using APT:
$> sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/lowercase-table-names select Enabled
download mysql from this url  link
